# Table Renaming in an Explicit Transaction

Tags: sql-server-2008, transactions, table-rename

I am extracting a subset of data from a backend system to load into a SQL table for querying by a number of local systems. I do not expect the dataset to ever be very large - no more than a few thousand records. The extract will run every two minutes on a SQL2008 server. The local systems are in use 24 x 7.

In my prototype, I extract the data into a staging table, then drop the live table and rename the staging table to become the live table in an explicit transaction.

```
   SELECT fieldlist 
        INTO Temp_MyTable_Staging
        FROM FOOBAR;
   BEGIN TRANSACTION
        IF(OBJECT_ID('dbo.MyTable') Is Not Null) 
            DROP TABLE MyTable;
        EXECUTE sp_rename N'dbo.Temp_MyTable_Staging', N'MyTable';
    COMMIT
```

I have found lots of posts on the theory of transactions and locks, but none that explain what actually happens if a scheduled job tries to query the table in the few milliseconds while the drop/rename executes. Does the scheduled job just wait a few moments, or does it terminate?
Conversely, what happens if the rename starts while a scheduled job is selecting from the live table? Does transaction fail to get a lock and therefore terminate?

Comment: One will block the other. The drop and rename will take out a `Sch-M` write lock, which blocks readers on the same lock. You might find this interesting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66427736/stored-procedure-truncate-table/66429140#66429140

Comment: By "blocks readers on the same lock", do you mean the reader will pause a few moments until the lock is released, or the that the read will fail?

Comment: Come to think of it, in this case you could still get a complete read failure. If someone queries the table after it has been dropped, then the query will fail to compile as the table doesn't exist at all to even take a lock on. But if another query is accessing the table then the `drop` will wait. As I said, personally I would use the partition switch trick as linked. See also https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89777/why-and-how-sometimes-i-get-the-absent-table-error-while-there-are-definitely

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain. Gives me a better understanding of why the partition switch is better. Will give me a good learning exercise

Comment: Normally, a writer takes out a modification lock, preventing reads or writes until it's transaction is committed. A reader takes out a shared lock, preventing writes. But here, the table is dropped, therefore a lock cannot be taken on it. Instead an error is thrown while compiling the query.

Comment: 'WAIT_AT_LOW_PRIORITY' gives syntax error on my 2008R2 system - I found another post that says this option was introduced in SQL2014?

Comment: You can leave out that `WITH` option, it's not necessary, just means it can cause blocking chains behind it if it's waiting on a long running query. But considering 2008R2 was end-of-life'd two years ago already, it might be time to upgrade.