# Strategies to delete most of the data from large table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization

I need to delete 90% of a table.

I am executing this statement in a loop (to keep the transactions small)

```
DELETE TOP(1000) 
FROM Events 
WHERE EventID IN (SELECT EventId FROM EventsToDelete)
```

Both tables have about 50 million rows.

Query plan for this statement is two index scans and this is not fast. What strategies could I employ to make this whole process faster ?

Other tables have FK references to this table.

Comment: *"Other tables have FK references to this table."* Do these have cascading on them too? If not, you might be better off dropping the `CONSTRAINT`s, `INSERT`ing the data you want to keep into a new table (with the same definition), `DROP`ing the existing table, renaming the new table, and then recreating the `CONSTRAINT`s. If they do, then it's not just 45M~ rows you're deleting, but all the rows in the related tables; that is very likely going to take some time.

Comment: I think this would work, but I do not like dropping the constraint because this assumes that I know all the constraints and I want the code to work even if a new constrain is setup... I guess no other way ?

Comment: You could create a new table and insert 10% from the source table.  Then drop the source table.

Comment: @SteveC even with constraints ?

Comment: Drop the constraints and recreate them afterwards. You may find this answer useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66427736/stored-procedure-truncate-table/66429140#66429140, it explains how to switch the data around quickly.

Comment: Perhaps the constraints may need to be replicated on the new table.  It all depends

Answer (score 1):

Try recasting your IN() as a JOIN.

```
DELETE TOP(1000) e
  FROM Events e
  JOIN EventsToDelete d ON e.EventId = d.EventId;
```

This may optimize the EventId matching.

A more complex but definitely faster scheme is this. In a loop, do this:

```
CREATE TABLE #ids AS 
SELECT TOP(5000) EventId FROM EventsToDelete;
DELETE e
  FROM Events e
  JOIN #ids d ON e.EventId = d.EventId;
DELETE  e
  FROM EventsToDelete e
  JOIN #ids d ON e.EventId = d.EventId;
DROP TABLE #ids;
```

I've had good success with large scale purges using this temp table strategy to gradually chew down the EventsToDelete list.

Precede your operations with

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
```

to avoid potential deadlocking.

And, you can probably use a batch size of 5k or 10k, which will get you fewer batches.

Finally, look at the Actual Execution Plan in SSMS to see if it recommends an index you don't have.

Comment: I'd add a unique index on #ids before joining the DELETE statements too; otherwise I fully agree this to be the fastest approach IMHO. (I assume there already is a unique (clustered?) index on `EventsToDelete` which means you can do the TOP(5000) with an ORDER BY as well without any extra cost as to make sure your id's to delete are nicely grouped together)