# Transactions - Keeping a table available for other queries until it's ready to be committed

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions

I have a stored procedure that takes awhile and rebuilds a file that other queries use for lookup.

So i want to:

1. Begin a transaction
2. Rebuild a table (takes awhile)
3. Commit the transaction

During step 2, I want other unrelated queries to read this table (without the in-progress updates.)  It's fine for me to see the data that was there before step 1 began.

And obviously, I don't want the query to wait for the transaction to finish.

Question: Are there parameters (like isolation level) that I need to specify on the transaction?   Do i need to do "with nolock" on the select statements?

if someone could point me in the right direction?  It's been a little hard to search for this.

Here's an mockup where i would want to query table IReallyWantToQueryThisTable while the stored procedure is running and see the data from before the transaction started:

```
create procedure bigoldlongprocedure
as
    Begin Tran Doit
        drop table if exists IReallyWantToQueryThisTable
        create table IReallyWantToQueryThisTable
        (Id int
        , dataforme varchar(20)
        )
        -- Takes a long time
        exec dbo.spReLoad_IReallyWantToQueryThisTable
    Commit Tran Doit
Return 0
```

Comment: I added the tag and mocked up a simplified example.

Comment: Does this help you? [Stored procedure - truncate table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66427736/stored-procedure-truncate-table/66429140#66429140)

Comment: I suggest you give this discussion [switching staging tables](https://littlekendra.com/2017/01/19/why-you-should-switch-in-staging-tables-instead-of-renaming/) a look. Seems you have a process that is kinda like an import ("rebuild" in your terminology).

Comment: I want to read the origial data that was present right at the point where the transaction started up until the transaction completes.  

What's the right option for that?

Comment: Nothing is free of consequences. Snapshot isolation might be useful (which has been hinted but not explained). Suggest you read this discussion of [snapshot isolation](https://www.sqlshack.com/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server/) as a start. What is best for your situation depends greatly on the activity that occurs within your database and the server instance. The staging table approach does not involve any application changes and might be simpler and easier to accomplish. But there are a lot of unknowns.

Comment: And note that "drop table if exists" is inconsistent with "I would want to query table ... and see the data from before". Dropping a table is an action that should not be taken lightly by application code. That removes permission, indexes, file assignment, triggers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to set any readable isolation level for the table IReallyWantToQueryThisTable in this transaction.
five types of isolation level for a transaction are
READ UNCOMMITTED
| READ COMMITTED
| REPEATABLE READ
| SNAPSHOT
| SERIALIZABLE
the table is unreadable for other tranc,just when setting SERIALIZABLE.so just make sure the isolation level in dbo.spreload is not SERIALIZABLE.

Comment: Great info.  Just so I'm sure, the default is what I want?

Comment: Isolation levels depend on what the *reader* session has set, `READ UNCOMMITTED` does not work on writers. Unless you set that isolation level then it will block. And it is anyway a really bad idea for a multitude of reasons.

Comment: I don't want to read the data as it rebuilds. I want to read the old data until the transaction commits.  Then switch to the new.  Is that "read Uncommited"?